# LeafletJs - Cannot set property 'L' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I'm using LeafletJs in my AngularJS (Version 1.5.8) project as a map, recently I have been using the unpkg.com URL - until recently I have however decided to use the locally downloaded code instead (there are several reasons why - one of them being the app working offline).

The problem I'm having now is whenever I even just load the script in the `index.html` file, I would get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'L' of undefined

Looking into the source code, the part of the code throwing the error is at the very start of the Javascript:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (factory((global.L = {}))); // This line is where the error is thrown.
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
// Here would now be the entire code of Leaflet.
```

While doing a bit more testing, `global` is coming in as `undefined`.

I haven't called Leaflet at all yet. Even commenting out all but this script will result in me still getting this error. I think it has something to do with Agular more than anything, but I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've managed to fix it. As I said earlier, `global` was `undefined`, so setting it to a default value of what it's supposed to be (In this case, a `Window`) has seemed to do the trick.

```
(function (global = Window, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (factory((global.L = {}))); // This line is where the error is thrown.
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
// Here would now be the entire code of Leaflet.
```

Setting `global = Window` instead of setting `(factory((Window.L = {})));` is so that it will still use the user's window information if it is not undefined. It seems to be working ok from my end on what I need to do.